# Can an arcpy.da.SearchCursor be used on a dataset residing in a ParcelFabric?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-2.7

I'm using ESRI's LocalGovernmentMI.gdb data model and am managaing parcel data in a [ParcelFabric](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//008500000002000000) dataset.  I'm trying to use a search cursor on the ParcelFabric_Parcels dataset but I recieve this ...

> RuntimeError: cannot open 'P:\Mapping\Data\LocalGovernmentMI.gdb\ParcelEditing\ParcelFabric\ParcelFabric_Parcels'

I'm using this but of code ...

```
import arcpy

fc = r'P:\Mapping\Data\LocalGovernmentMI.gdb\ParcelEditing\ParcelFabric\ParcelFabric_Parcels'
field = "Name"

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, field) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print (row)
```

If I export the dataset and run the search cursor on that data it works.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm in the processe of trying to build a Python add-in tool that takes an input value ( user clicks on a parcel, a SelectByLocation task is executed using a PointGeometry, then the value from the "Name" field of that selected parcel is passed to the search cursor which will help identify all parcels having that value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Arcpy.da.SearchCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000) accepts, "feature class, layer, table, or table view" as the in_table.  After looking at the Parcel Fabric page, I would suggest [Make Parcel Fabric Table View (Parcel Fabric)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009000000007000000).  This will give you a temporary table to use with the cursor.

Comment: Thank you, this works.  Would have been better to use the cursor on the parcel fabric dataset, but i'll still take it.